# Eclipse eReviewBoard: how to set the server

Tags: eclipse, review-board

I am trying to install eReviewBoard in Eclipse Neon. After I selected the task repository type (Reviewboard), I have no idea how to set the information about the server: Server, Label, User ID, and Password.

Do I need to register an account somewhere? If yes, where? If no, how am I supposed to fill those data?

I didn't find any documentation about this after googling for a long time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is this an internal Review Board instance? Generally, internal Review Board instances are hooked up to the LDAP system and you can point `Server` to the cname along with your LDAP username and password.

If it is a public instance, the credentials are the same that you use to login. For example,

username: guest6366
password: demo

http://demo.reviewboard.org/account/login/

This is so authentication can be done with the remote Review Board server on API calls.